# GCP Build with Google Run always create a new service why?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hi have a basic CI/CD setup

Whenever I push new code on my GitHub repository (trigger).

It should push it via Google Build to Google Run

But currently, whenever the trigger is initiated, it creates a new service on my cloud account.

Now, I am not sure why it's happening!

What I want is to update the current running service on Google Run

or

Create a new service, migrate 100% traffic to it and delete the old one.

This is my Deployment screen looks like. I have highlighted the section which I believe might be the reason for this duplicate services.

[image]

Comment: Create a new service or a new revision in the same service name?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new service or a new revision as suggested by Guillaume Blaquiere?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere creates a new revision, I guess. But I am scared that it will cost more every time it creates a new revision.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy a new version of your service (a new version can be a new image, or the same image with different parameters (concurrency, min/max instance, CPU, env vars,...)), it's named a revision. There is no limit on the number of revision (in fact yes, you have a limit at 1000, then the oldest will be deleted when a new one is created).

The pricing model of Cloud Run (and other serverless product) is simple: you pay when your service is running. In your case, you haven't a min instance parameter, and therefore your revision will run (and you will start to pay) when  request invokes your service (and you pay only when you go over the [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier))

Same thing for Cloud Build: you start to pay when you use it. And you use it every time you push your code on GitHub (that invoke a Cloud Build trigger and then deploy your code on Cloud Run). Here again, you have a comfortable free tiers of 120 minutes free per day for Cloud Build.

Comment: how do I make sure that everytime i push my code to github it just update the current instance of my google run app?

Comment: The triggers are made for that. And you update a service, with a new revision. The instance are the "VM" (or similar) that run a revision of your service. You never update an instance, the instance are destroyed after a while by Google Cloud and a new one created, with the new version when new request comes in.